# Map string to unique 0..1 float value, while keeping order

Tags: algorithm, mapping, redis

I would like to use Redis to sort string values (using sorted sets), but I can only use floats for that purpose.  I am looking for an algorithm to convert string to a float 0..1 value, while keeping order.

I mean that s1 < s2 (alphabetically) should imply that f(s1) < f(s2).

Is there such an algorithm?

**P.S.** I will use such an algorithm for sorting usernames and in the most cases players with matching scores would have quite different usernames. So in the most cases either approach should work, but there is still room for collisions. On the other hand strings will be sorted moreless properly and it's acceptable if almost the same usernames are sorted incorrectly.

Comment: Have you considered using the redis `sort` feature?

Answer (score 3):

Each character can be mapped to its [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) number. If you convert each string to its float equivalent concatenating all the ASCII numbers (with eventually zeros in front of them so that all characters will be mapped to three numbers) you will keep ordering. **But** if your strings are long, your floats will be huge and your mapping might not be unique (if several strings begin with the same characters, due to rounding inside the floats).

For example:

```
'hello' -> 104101108108111
```

If you know which subsets of characters your strings contain (for instance, only lowercase letters, or only uppercase letters and numbers) you can create your own mapping to use less numbers per character.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, such an algorithm exists and is trivial: Simply put a radix point (“.”) before the string and interpret it as a base-256 numeral (assuming your string uses 8-bit characters). Analogously, if your string had just the characters “0” to “9”, you would read it as a decimal numeral, such as .58229 for the string “58229”. You are doing the same thing, just with base 256 instead of base 10.

Practically, this is not possible without a severely restricted set of potential strings or special floating-point software. Since a typical floating-point object has a finite size, it has a finite number of possible values. E.g., a floating-point object with 64 bits has at most 2<sup>64</sup> values, even neglecting those that stand for special notions such as NaN. Conversely, a string of arbitrary length has infinitely many potential values. Even if you limit the string to something reasonable in today’s computer memories, it has hugely more potential values than a normal floating-point object does.

To solve this, you must either decrease the number of potential strings (by limiting their length or otherwise restricting which strings are allowed) or increase the number of potential floating-point values (perhaps by using special arbitrary-precision floating-point software).